# Electron not updating the edited index.html completely in the app

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

i have just started brushing up with electron and as a starter , i cloned this simple electron-tutorial-app to see how things work.(everything works fine with the official electron starter app).

git repo used: https://github.com/crilleengvall/electron-tutorial-app

i am not including the scripts since it is all available there.

What i have modified: edited the index.html and sections->welcome.html as shown

What is the error:  the expected changes wasnt rendered in the electron app.

(note: i have not changed anything in .js or any .css files)

original UI (from the repo):
[image]

changes in index.html (expected changes in left panel of UI):
[image]

changes in sections->welcome.html (expected changes in main panel of UI):
[image]

Now,after i made those changes and ran the app, i get this.
(see on left panel , i get "bacon" and on main panel "testing" header is rendered but the paragarph under it isnt changed.)
[image]

i am a bit confused what is happenning becuase i did some googling and thought it might be session cache issue but again, part is it is being edited and part isnt.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit strings in translations/en.js , because this is solution with localization (localization - adapting computer software to different languages).

So, if you want to change sidebar strings, you need to edit this in en.js:

```
"Welcome": "Welcome", 
"Who we are": "IPC/Remote", 
"What we do": "What we do", 
"Get in touch": "Get in touch"
```

Comment: SOLVED IT. you were right. thank you very much. i got to learn about js i18n too today.